# Fingerprint error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

After bundle executes rake assets:precompile, git pushes to Heroku master, which shows this in source:

http://www.yunhuafangartstudio.com/sw2015

But, my development is OK:

https://rails-tutorial-weilwang.c9.io/sw2015

Not sure what is going on?

Comment: Your question needs to provide more context and stand on its own better. Please include stuff from the links to clarify your question. Links can become outdated and broken.

Comment: I precompile to S3, it was OK before, but today, it didn't generate fingerprint <img src="http://yunhuafang.s3.amazonaws.com/images/MG_4869ab.jpg" alt="Mg 4869ab">; on my development, it looks OK, <img src="/assets/MG_4869ab-495c527837f708be01b89cca4062390f6230a50416248fc1335acea8118f6e3f.jpg" alt="Mg 4869ab 495c527837f708be01b89cca4062390f6230a50416248fc1335acea8118f6e3f">

Comment: it looks like I cannot have /public/assets inside the .gitignore. instead, i have to empty /public/assets before git push heroku.